# IdentityServer 4 and pre-existing SQL server databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, identityserver4

Is it possible to set up Identity server so that it not only looks at a SQL database when it comes to user records, but uses a pre-existing database that contains all the details? How would I go about configuring Identity Server to look at certain tables and fields within a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can implement your own `IProfileService` which has your UserDbContext or UserRepository injected into it. Make sure you add this service to the DI container for it to work. IdentityServer4 will your implementation of `IProfileService` if you do this.